# NextAuth fetching api endpoint - req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to use NextAuth.js for authentication in my Next.js app, using the following code from documentation:

```
  authorize: async(credentials, req) => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/userverify", {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    const user = await res.json()

    if (res.ok && user) {
      return user
    }
    return null
  }
```

The problem is the actual fetching. In the userverify.js I have this code:

```
export default async function verify(res, req) {
  const credentials = req.body
  console.log(credentials)
  const user = await findUser(credentials.email)
  if (user) {
    if (await argon2.verify(req.body.password, user.password)) {
      res.status(200).send(user)
      return user
    }
    else {
      res.status(401).send("Credentials Incorrect")
    }
  }
}
```

`req.body` in this file is undefined. I'm not using Express.js, only Next.js built in api routes.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the order of arguments. did you try logging `req` and `res`. First argument is `request` and second is `response`:

```
export default async function verify(req, res){
```

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Comment: i fixed it by using typescript and define that req is NextApiRequest and res is NextApiResponse.. –

Answer (score 0):

Change the absolute endpoint to a relative endpoint, from:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/userverify", {...
```

to:

```
await fetch("/api/userverify", {...
```

Explanation:

When you use an absolute endpoint, the browser sends a preflight request, `OPTIONS` request, that does not have `body` in it. That's why you get an undefined `req.body`.

You can verify it by checking your `req.method`, and see that no `POST` method is sent, but only an `OPTIONS` method.

By the way, if you use curl or Postman, the endpoint will work just fine. The decision to send `OPTIONS` request is made by the browser that validates CORS (cross-origin resource sharing).

Notwithstanding, if you have to use an absolute path, you should handle the OPTIONS request first by sending a 200 status after checking the origin and setting a header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your allowed domains, and then you would get the actual POST request from the browser, with the body you wished for.